# excel : format dates so that they include the day of the week in full letters

Tags: excel

In excel 2007, how can I format my dates so that they include the day of the week in full letters ? I've tried typing around but I just can't guess it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the cell - cell formating, then select date on the left pane, and select format type on the right pane. 
Or is this a programing question ?

Answer (score 17):

Try using dddd for the day part of your format string e.g. dddd MMMM MM yyyy will give Wednesday December 14 2011

Comment: You can also use `ddd` to get `Wed` instead of `Wednesday`.

Answer (score 5):

For UK/non-US date format users the following may help:-

dddd dd mmmm  yyyy

which gives a date format of  **Friday 18 April 2014**

Answer (score 4):

right click - format cell - custom - ddd, dd-mmm-yy.
This will give day & date as example: Tue, 21-Jul-15

right click - format cell - custom - dddd, dd-mmm-yy.
This will give day & date as example: Tuesday, 21-Jul-15

right click - format cell - custom - dddd, dd/mmm/yyyy.
This will give day & date as example: Tuesday, 21/Jul/15

You can choose the format you wish. I recommend Tue, 21-Jul-15 format

Answer (score 1):

I use this equation to give a 3 character day name, like SUN for Sunday:

```
    =IF(A1="","",MID("SUNMONTUEWEDTHUFRISAT",3*WEEKDAY(A1)-2,3))
```

This example assumes you have a date displayed in cell A1, and you want the corresponding 3 letter day name in cell B1.
The IF portion is optional, but it keeps the function from displaying SAT if cell A1 is blank.

If you want the full day text version of this it would be:

```
    =IF(A8="","",TRIM(MID("Sunday   Monday   Tuesday  WednesdayThursday Friday   Saturday ",9*WEEKDAY(A8)-8,9)))
```